# avg # of guesses it takes to pick a certain number between 1-100 (random choices)

Tags: probability

essentially...

a square on a 10x10 board is randomly assigned the letter X

what is the avg # of times it would take to guess that position while randomly guessing one at a time and not choosing numbers already guessed

my intuition says it involves binomial / geometric series??

thanks for any hints

Comment: Could you calculate this for $1$ square? $2$? $3$? Can you spot a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: As the only information you get is whether or not you're correct, it's equivalent to simply set the order of squares you will pick in advance. There are $100!$ such orderings.

Can you construct the expected value of the index of any particular number in a randomly chosen ordering, for example by pairing an ordering with its reverse?

Comment: what do you mean by expected value of the index? I understand the 100! so I'm guessing it's some value divided by 100! ?

Comment: @user1990406 If you're trying to pick the integer $1\leq x\leq 100$, and your order of guesses is $a_1,a_2,a_{100}$, the index is the integer $1\leq i\leq 100$ for which $a_i=x$. In other words, it's the number of guesses you need before you hit $x$.

Comment: so the expected value of the index would be 50? if you pair 1..2..3..100 it with it's reverse 100..99..98..1 the expected value of any index is 50? or?

Comment: @user1990406 Almost --- you pair $1$ with $100$, $2$ with $99$, etc.

Comment: would the expected value of the index still be 50? despite my misinterpretation

Comment: @user1990406 Not quite; since you're pairing $i$ with $101-i$ the expected value is $\frac{101}{2}$, not $50=\frac{100}{2}$.

Comment: wow OK I see... cool how that is == to the summation provided by the other answer...  I just don't understand how you had the instinct to put the two orderings next to each other? just because it's one of the possible 100! orderings? and easy to examine?

Comment: @user1990406 The main idea of it is once you've reduced the problem to orderings, no one location (first guess, 37th guess, etc.) is "special" in any way, and so the expected value of the number of guesses is just the average location (index). This can be formalized by many different techniques - you can count the number of orderings that give the correct guess in any particular location, you can pair orderings (like I did; Gauss's proof of the formula for $1+2+\cdots+n$ is where I drew inspiration), you can use cyclic shifts of orderings to establish equal probabilities directly...

Comment: OK my last question is (and thank you so much for everything) is "As the only information you get is whether or not you're correct, it's equivalent to simply set the order of squares you will pick in advance. There are 100! such orderings." how did you draw this conclusion of equivalency?

Comment: I guess I don't really understand "it's equivalent to simply set the order of squares you will pick in advance"

Comment: wait i see... because it's completely random you are able to outright show all the possible ways you will guess 1-100

Answer (score 0):

The probability we choose the correct spot on the first try is $\frac{1}{100}$. The probability we don’t choose the correct spot on the first try is $\frac{99}{100}$.

If we don’t choose the correct spot (and that has $\frac{99}{100}$ probability), the probability we choose the correct spot on the second try is $\frac{1}{99}$.

---

Notice the probability we choose the correct spot on the second attempt $\frac{99}{100} \cdot \frac{1}{99}$ (by the multiplication principle) is the same as the probability we chose the correct spot on our first try. Indeed, one can see that the probability of choosing the correct position on the $N$ th try, where $N \in \{1,2,3,...,100\}$ is $\frac{1}{100}$.

---

$$E(N)=\sum_{N=1}^{100} NP(N)$$

$$=\sum_{N=1}^{100} N \left(\frac{1}{100}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1+2+3+...+100}{100}$$

This is the average of first $100$ positive integers, which is $\frac{100+1}{2}=51.5$.

Comment: so would this be a Bernoulli distribution with 100 bernoulli trials with p = 1/100?

Comment: You can say that the distribution of choosing the correct spot on exactly any specific trial follows a Bernoulli distribution with $p=1/100$. @user1990406